# Powerbuilder implementing SFTP functionality

Tags: c++, file-upload, dll, sftp, powerbuilder

Powerbuilder does not seem to have a SFTP functionality built in (Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I couldn't find it anywhere in the documentation).

I'm assuming I have to import C/C++ DLL of SFTP to handle this problem, but I'd like to know if there's any better alternatives.

Also, are there any examples I can look at for how SFTP is done in powerbuilder?

I'm using Powerbuilder 10.2.1

Answer (score 1):

You might look at this sample:

http://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode_ftpclient.html

When you do the HttpOpenRequest one of the flags that is passed will indicate whether it should be a secure connection (INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE).

There are also third party controls that would make it easier.  For example

Dart:  http://www.dart.com/samp_powerbuilder.aspx

WeOnlyDo software:  http://nathanepralle.ulitzer.com/node/220784/mobile

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you happen to know if the component from topwizprogramming supports public/private key authentication?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

The Topwiz FTPClient example does not do SFTP, just regular FTP. It is just a really fancy shell over WinInet.dll (part of Internet Explorer). WinInet.dll does not support SFTP. I would recommend using a 3rd party ActiveX control.

I have used this one from Classic ASP with good results:

http://www.activexperts.com/network-component/

Comment: Thank you. I'm actually looking for a free component, so if there aren't any available, I think I'll just go ahead and import a C++ dll.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .NET dll and use it from PB as COM component using [Tamir SharpSSH library](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx), an open source SSH library for .NET.